# Hosting WF as Windows Service

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I am trying to construct a simple windows workflow to monitor a directory for inbound files and do some DB updates using Windows WF 4.0. Currently I am planning to build a 'WCF Workflow Service' and host it as a 'Windows service' running 24/7 (with a daily service shutdown and startup).

Further in the future I am planning to consume this service using an ASP.NET/WPF application to create a basic dashboard kind of stuff.

Considering the idea of directory polling for files with WF hosted on windows service, does it seems to be a good idea? What can be the cons of this?

Please advice if there are any drawbacks on this or can this achieved by better means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm actually doing this, but it is a bit more complex than you think, and should be avoided if possible.

You should not be blocking from within an Activity; if it is expected to be a long running Activity that is waiting from input from the outside (FileSystemWatcher event, for instance), the workflow should idle itself and wait to be woken from the outside.

How I did this was I created a workflow extension that hosted the FileSystemWatcher.  Once the Activity was ready to watch for a file, it created a bookmark and passed it to the extension.

The extension then started the FSW, holding onto the bookmark.

When a FSW event was fired, the extension resumed the bookmark, passing in an object that contained details about the event.  The Activity did what was needed with the event, then re-scheduled itself.

Normally I wouldn't have done this, but I had some requirements that forced me to use WF4 to accomplish this goal.  If I didn't have to use WF4, I would have just spun up the FSW within the service and consumed the events.

Unless you expect to have to be very flexible with your configuration detailing what you do with the FSW event, and expect this to change relatively often during deployment of the service, I'd skip WF4.

Comment: Thanks Will. Does that mean WF are not designed cater such needs like directory/file monitoring ? Aren't such activities very common in any industry which uses SOA ? Will it be good to consider some round-about fashion to achieve it still using WF?

Comment: @Sriraj.P: There are no baked-in activities for monitoring directories.  Monitoring directories is kind of old school; who the hell drops a file in a directory nowadays?  Oh, wait, I have to do this.  So you have to roll it yourself.  As my answer suggests, you can achieve it correctly using the round-about fashion I described.  I would not recommend it *unless you have a very good reason to use Workflow Foundation 4 to monitor directories.*  In your case, it might be better to monitor the directory, then *spawn WF to act on the contents of any created files*.  Best of both worlds, I suppose.

Comment: That seems to be the way. Thanks for your input !

Comment: Directory monitoring seems old - but still a bunch of insurance/banking organizations to share data files in this fashion. I was thinking about working around FSW like moving the set of files I need to work to a different directory so that I know whatever in inbound files folder is fresh. Any thoughts?